# What is the rank of the pure state?

Tags: quantum-state, state-tomography

Consider pure or nearly pure quantum state, is it usually low-rank? Can you give a example of a concrete state and its rank?

Comment: Pure states by definition have rank one

Comment: Thank you, but why? Does the N&C book contain this ?

Comment: Sure it does. It's by definition a projector onto a one-dimensional subspace ...

Comment: I find only from Exercise 2.73: A minimal ensemble for $\rho$ is an ensemble containing a number of elements equal to the rank of $\rho$.

Comment: The rank is the dimension of the image. A pure state is a state of the form $\rho = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$, in particular it is an orthogonal projection onto the one-dimensional subspace spanned by the vector $\psi$. In formula, $\mathrm{im}(\rho) = \mathrm{span}(\psi)$, thus $\mathrm{rk}(\rho) = 1$. Or in the language of that exercise: a pure state is an ensemble containing exactly one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure state is by definition rank one, $\rho = | \psi \rangle\langle \psi |$.

A state can have maximal rank and be arbitrarily close to a pure state. Just mix a pure state with the maximally mixed state, i.e. $\rho := (1-\varepsilon)| \psi \rangle\langle \psi | + \varepsilon \mathrm{I}/d$. This state is of maximal rank $d$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: So only pure states have the rank one, the rank of mixed states will larger than 1?

Comment: @KarryMa Exactly, pure states are the quantum states with rank one. Consequently, mixed (non-pure) states have higher rank.